# проверка переменой str из списка

Tags: python, if, python-3.6

недавно начал программировать на python.
решил по курсу написать лёгкого голосового помощника, всё получается, но есть одно но.

```
def working(task):
    if "привет" == task: 
        talk("Привет!")
    elif "пока" in task: 
        talk("Пока!")
```

дело в том, что я хочу использовать список, и что бы не только одно слово проверялось а проверялись все варианты, допустим возьму лёгкий список:
"ctime": ('текущее время','сейчас времени','который час'),

хочу что бы при всех этих словах у меня появлялся нужный мне результат, но не могу додуматься.
может я что то упускаю...

Comment: Простая проверка на вхождение в список - `if  txt  in  ['текущее время', 'сейчас времени', 'который час']:`. Где `txt` - это ваш текст, который нужно сравнить с допустимыми вариантами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самым простым и лучшем решением будет перебор данных словоря
Представим что словарь с возможными вариантами будет под именем **data** 
Тогда код можно написать следующим образом:

```py
data = {"ctime":[...]}
def working(task):
 if task in data['ctime']:
  ...
```

Comment: спасибо, мне помогло.